LabView vi freezes during exiting event structure

I've attached a PNG of my VI for reference. I'm facing an issue with the event structure in my code. This is a simplified version of my main VI to highlight the problem.
The issue arises when I press the "Stop" button and then attempt to update the values of the Numeric 7 and Numeric 9 controls—the VI freezes. In my actual application, this small piece of code is part of a much larger VI, and when it freezes, the entire VI becomes unresponsive.
For demonstration purposes, I've used simple numeric controls here to replicate the issue. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
One possible solution is to remove the event structure entirely, but that leads to another problem: the numeric values update continuously, which isn't viable for my main VI. In the actual application, instead of just two controls, I use a control connected to a step motor that also updates continuously. This makes the event structure essential for proper functionality.
I would appreciate any advice or insights you might have on this issue. Thank you!
I was expecting the vi to run smoothly even though i was updating the event structure controls with pressed stop button. But instead, the vi freezes.

What's the toggle behavior of the button? Also, normally you make pressing the stop button a separate event case of the event structure. That way you don't need to have a timeout or polling interval at all

the toggle behavior is "switch when pressed". I also tried to put the button into a seperate event case but i saw no difference

The issue and workaround are described here: https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Event-Structure-dependency-freezes-panel/td-p/4352324 As noted there, it is bad practice to prevent the event loop from running for extended periods of time. You should restructure your code to avoid this

From your description it sounds like your event structure is embedded into a larger VI that keeps running after the stop button was pressed. Something like this:

There are two issues with this. One has been pointed out by the other answers and is that the stop button handling is not best-practice. It should be handled by the event structure itself. Like this (only the left side):

However, that does not fix your issue. Poor button handling leads to higher CPU utilization, sluggish behavior, and missed button presses. But it does not freeze the entire VI.
The freezing of the UI that you observe happens when a UI event occurs that is registered with an event structure but that structure is not executed. As you describe it, it can be triggered by the following order of operations:

Start the VI
Press the stop button, causing the event loop to quit but not the whole VI (since the second loop still runs)
Change the numeric input

By default, the front panel (and only the front panel) will block until all user events have been processed. Since the event loop no longer runs, this will never happen. You can prevent this by unchecking the corresponding box in the event structure configuration marked here:

This issue is also described on the NI forums here: https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Event-Structure-dependency-freezes-panel/td-p/4352324
Note the warning written there: Unchecking this option is a nasty workaround and can have unforeseen consequences. You should instead restructure your code to avoid this situation from occurring. Details of how to do this require more context from you. However, consider the following options:

Move periodic activities such as checking external devices into the timeout action of the event loop
Use a custom user event to notify the event loop when all other activities have stopped and it can terminate itself
Disable and grey out UI elements associated with the event loop once it quits
Re-enter the event loop soon after exiting it. Depending on the use case you can even have it execute with a timeout of zero and stop it again once the timeout occurs. This only processes queued up events

Option 1 requires the least amount of code but only works decently if the periodic operations finish very quickly.
Option 2 is the cleanest and leads to the most responsive UI.
Option 3 is itself more of a workaround but can work well in a pinch or if it is desirable to tell the user that their input is no longer being processed.

I can’t say exactly why you’re hanging. I will say this stop mechanism is non-standard. So try the following simple change to make it standard:
Add a Value Changed event case for the Stop button, and put the Stop FP terminal inside that case.
That will guarantee that the event structure wakes up consistently on the same iteration as the stop signal.

It hangs because the front panel will always freeze until the event loop can process events. If the loop is stopped, even with proper stop button handling, it will deadlock. See the link I posted above.

@Homer512 that is one of several possible problems given the diagram shown. I said I couldn’t say because there are multiple possible issues.

The point is that the reported error mode is that the VI freezes. If the button press is missed by the loop, it does not freeze. What does freeze the VI (or specifically the front panel) is when a UI event that is registered with an event structure occurs while the event structure is not executed, meaning while the loop is stopped but the VI itself still runs. Fixing the stop button is good practice but it will not fix the issue reported by OP.

Where in the picture posted do you get that there’s a long-running process? Updating 9 numeric controls should be fairly quick. And it wouldn’t hang only when Stop is pressed.

It's not in the picture. It's in the text. OP presses stop. Then changes the numeric input (which implies that the VI is still running at this time), then it freezes. That is easy to reproduce with or without proper button handling. But you know what? I'll make a separate answer. I didn't want to, since the workaround is better described on the NI forums. But apparently it's not obvious

@Homer512 Ah. I see now. I misunderstood that aspect of the question.

It'll be your toggle behaviour.
You're logic got a few oddities. The 50 ms. wait time and the 100 ms. timeout time are a conflicting, when using an event structure, try to use only events (same goes for the stop button).
You've got an event in a while loop, your logic should be written in a way that when the while loop finishes (stop condition == true), you should finish the whole VI execution.
